# How to run C++ files in OpenBR?

Tags: c++, qt, openbr

Sorry if the documentation is clear on this, but I'm having a hard time running C++ files in OpenBR. I've tried running them through the terminal via g++ and via the QT interface to no avail.

Ultimately I don't see any way to create (nuanced) custom OpenBR scripts than by using the C++ API, but I can't even run the provided demos (age_estimation.cpp, face_recognition.cpp etc.).

I'm running this on Ubuntu for reference.

Answer (score 0):

To run the example files you first have to download the dataset. The scripts/downloadDatasets.sh is in the openbr directory.

In the qt interface after opening the upmost CMakeList and building openbr you can select what to run on the bottom of the left toolbar, and then click the "play" arrow below to run the executable.